# Higher part of multiply and division in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

When I multiply a pair of 4 bytes integers in assembly, the lower part of the result is in EAX and the higher part in EDX. If I am in C or C++ and I want to get the higher part, is it possible whithout use of inline assembly?

Is in the same way possible to get the integer division result from EAX and the modulus result from EDX without repeating the division in C or C++? I actually only know to do first `a/b` and then `a%b`, while in assembler both results are given in the same operation.

Comment: Sure. If `x` is a 64-bit long int, you can use `(x >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF` to get the high 4 bytes.

Comment: Hint: Look for a data type that is larger than `int`.

Comment: I dispute that premise. On my DS9k machine, the output of the multiplication is written to a time-dependent 157-bit I/O port.

Comment: Answer to your second question (hopefully): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008997/higher-part-of-multiply-in-c-or-c# The TL;DR is that if you just do `a/b` and `a%b` they're probably optimized to one division instruction in the end, and otherwise you can try `std::div`.

Comment: Hint #2: [`div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div).

Comment: @KerrekSB: the x86 registers were given as an example. From my link: "On many platforms, a single CPU instruction obtains both the quotient and the remainder, and this function may leverage that, although compilers are generally able to merge nearby / and % where suitable."

Comment: @Jongware: yes yes, the answer is of course to use `div`, but that has nothing to do with any kind of registers, nor does it require assuming anything about registers.

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++ for this answer. Are you satisfied with a compiler-specific answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it easily in C this way:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t a, b;  // input
uint64_t val = (uint64_t)a * b;
uint32_t high = val >> 32, low = val;
```

Leave it to the compiler to produce the best possible code.  Modern optimizers are really good at it.  Hand coded assembly often looks better but performs worse.

As commented by Pete Becker, the above relies on availability of the types `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.  If you insist on die hard portability (say you are programming on a `DS9K`), you may instead use the types `uint_least32_t` and `uint_least64_t` or `uint_fast32_t` and `uint_fast64_t` that are always available under C99, but you need an extra mask, that will be optimized out if not required:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint_fast32_t a, b;  // input
uint_fast64_t val = (uint_fast64_t)a * b;
uint_fast32_t high = (val >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF, low = val & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Regarding division, you can use the C99 library functions `div`, `ldiv` or `lldiv` to perform signed division and remainder operations in one call.  The division/modulo combination will be implemented in one operation if possible on the target architecture for the specific operand types.

It may be more efficient to write both expressions and rely on the compiler to detect the pattern and produce code that uses a single IDIV opcode:

```
struct divmod_t { int quo, rem; };
struct divmod_t divmod(int num, int denom) {
    struct divmod_t r = { num / denom, num % denom };
    return r;
}
```

Testing on [Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/oOvl17) shows both clang and gcc generate a single `idiv` instruction for this code at `-O3`.

You can turn one of these divisions into a multiplication:

```
struct divmod_t { int quo, rem; };
struct divmod_t divmod2(int num, int denom) {
    struct divmod_t r;
    r.quo = num / denom;
    r.rem = num - r.quo * denom;
    return r;
}
```

Note that the above functions do not check for potential overflow, which results in undefined behavior.  Overflow occurs if `denom = 0` and if `num = INT_MIN` and `denom = -1`.

Comment: Just a tad simpler than C++ ;-)

Comment: wish one could do that in C++ - why does C++ have to be *so* complicated?!! :P

Comment: @PaulEvans Because you should be using the language *after* it's been improved (i.e. ++C), not before ;)

Comment: @tonysdg *now* you tell me! :)

Comment: You cannot have both worlds: C/C++ invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: This is also valid C++11

Comment: This assumes that the hardware has both a 32-bit and a 64-bit native type. If it doesn't, the corresponding `uintxx_t` type will not be defined. Use `uint_least32_t` or `uint_fast32_t` instead.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You are correct, this answer assumes that.  Yet it would take some **very** exotic hardware to not have such types: C99 specifies `long long` as having at least 64 bits.

Comment: @chqrlie - you call it "die-hard portability", I call the opposite "gratuitous non-portability". <g> Almost every use of fixed-size types that I've seen on SO is unnecessary.

Comment: The real gratuitous headache is the fact that `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` with the attached semantics are not mandated by the C standard.  It would not be so much work for the compiler to emulate them on the rare architectures where they are not native.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Thank you for insisting, I was really surprised they did not.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

You don't deal with the implementation details in C or C++.  That's the whole point. If you want the the most significant bytes, simple use the language. Right shift `>>` is designed to do that. Something like:

```
uint64_t i;
uint32_t a;
uint32_t b;
// input a, b and set i to a * b
// this should be done with (thanks to @nnn, pls see comment below):
// i = a; i *= b;
uint64_t msb = i >> 32;
```

Comment: Just to avoid any uncertainty, it should be noted that doing `i = a * b;` is not ok, as only the 32 LSBits will be stored. Either one of the operands should have a cast to `uint64_t`, or having something like `i = a; i *= b;`

Answer (score 2):

For multiplication, only Forth among widely known languages (higher than assembler) has an explicit multiplication of N*N bits to 2N-bit result (the words `M*`, `UM*`). C, Fortran, etc. don't have it. Yes, this sometimes leads into misoptimization. For example, on x86_32, getting a 64-bit product requires either converting a number to 64-bit one (can cause library call instead of `mul` command), or an explicit inline assembly call (simple and efficient in gcc and clones, but not always in MSVC and other compilers).

In my tests on x86_32 (i386), a modern compiler is able to convert code like

```
#include <stdint.h>
int64_t mm(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  return (int64_t) x * y;
}
```

to simple "imull" instruction without a library call; clang 3.4 (-O1 or higher) and gcc 4.8 (-O2 or higher) satisfies this, and I guess this won't stop ever. (With lesser optimization level, a second useless multiplication is added.) But one can't guarantee this for any other compiler without a real test. With gcc on x86, the following will work even without optimization:

```
int64_t mm(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  int64_t r;
  asm("imull %[s]" : "=A" (r): "a" (x), [s] "bcdSD" (y): "cc");
  return r;
}
```

The same trend, with similar commands, is true for nearly all modern CPUs.

For division (like 64-bit dividend by 32-bit divisor to 32-bit quotient and remainders), this is more complicated. There are library functions like `lldiv' but they are only for signed division; there are no unsigned equivalents. Also, they are library calls with the all respective cost. But, the issue here is that many modern architectures doesn't have this kind of division. For example, it's explicitly excluded from ARM64 and RISC-V. For them, one have to emulate long division using shorter one (e.g. divide 2**(N-1) by a dividend but then double the result and tune its remainder). For those having mixed-length division (x86, M68k, S/390, etc.), a one-line assembly inliner is rather good if you are sure it won't overflow :)

Some architectures lacks division support at all (older Sparc, Alpha), and that's a standard library task to support such operations.

Anyway, a standard library provides all needed operations unless you require the highest precision (e.g. x86_64 can divide 128-bit dividend by 64-bit divisor, but this isn't supported by C library).

I think the most elaborated and accessible example of these approaches for different architectures is [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/). It's much more advanced than for your question, but you can dig examples for division by a single limb for different architectures, it implements proper chaining even if architecture doesn't support it directly. Also it will suffice very most needs for arbitrary long number arithmetic, despite with some overhead.

NB if you call `div`-like instruction explicitly, it's your responsibility to check for overflows. It's more trickier in signed case than in unsigned one; for example, division of -2147483648 by -1 crashes a x86-based program, even if written in C.

UPDATE[2020-07-04]: with GCC [Integer overflow builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html), one can use multiplication using mixed precision, like:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
int64_t mm(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  int64_t result;
  __builtin_mul_overflow(x, y, &result);
  return result;
}
```

this is translated by both GCC and Clang to optimal form in most of cases. I hope other compilers and even standards will eventually adopt this.

Comment: This one is tricky: `-2147483648 / -1` is OK because `2147483648` is not a 32-bit integer constant. It is either an `int`, a `long` or a `long long`, depending on which type has more than 31 value bits. `long long` is guaranteed to have at least 63 value bits. To exhibit the problem, write `INT32_MAX / -1` or `(int32_t)-2147483648 / -1`. You can also use `int32_t` variables with the appropriate values.

Comment: @chqrlie yep, a compiler tries to make as more calculations at compile time as possible. The simplest approach to reliably disable such optimization is to use volatile variables.

Answer (score 1):

For division, a fully portable solution uses one of the library function `div`, `ldiv`, or `lldiv`.

Comment: These library routines support only signed division. The original poster didn't specify signedness of desired operations.