# DIVQ counterpart on ARM / AArch64 (narrowing division with double-width dividend)?

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, division, arm64

x86-64 has an instruction, DIVQ, to divide 128-bits number by 64-bits number.

Does ARM64 have anything similar? How to perform 128/64 division on ARM64?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ARM architecture reference](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/ga/) is your go-to for questions like this.

The answer is no, [ARM does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34017672/327083) division with 128-bit dividends.  Your option is to implement division on longer operands in emulation.  Any big integer library should serve as a suitable reference for algorithms to that end.

Comment: For the specific case of 2R / R division, the libgcc implementation of uint64_t division for 32-bit ARM might be a good example, for the case where the divisor fits in 32 bits but the dividend doesn't.  Or the unsigned __int128 / __int128 division helper function for AArch64, `__udivti3`. https://godbolt.org/z/oe6Txs4rd.  C source for LLVM's version in https://code.woboq.org/llvm/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/udivti3.c.html -> https://code.woboq.org/llvm/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/udivmodti4.c.html#__udivmodti4

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed - or for a hack and slash, pick a language, compile a divide, and inspect the assembly.  Dare I call it *"compile a divide and conquer"*?

Comment: The usual languages for that are C and C++, and most compilers don't inline the helper function.  You get `bl __udivti3` from GCC (and I assume clang), as shown in the Godbolt link.  (It does tell you what helper-function name to look for though, that's why I linked it.)  So yes, just *compile a divide and conquer* is a multi-step process, possibly even recursive if you have to compile `libgcc` sources to get the AArch64 asm you want :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Well...like all oversimple  plans, quite easier said than done :)